# get line number form R browser() after do.call

Tags: r, debugging

I'm trying to debug a function in which there are a certain number of browser() calls , and when one of them is triggered,  I want to know which one is it.
The problem is that this function is called via do.call , and that apparently makes browser print all its arguments (not its names, the real arguments), which are a few million lines long, so basically is a mess, as the line number is printed before the millions of lines.
If I try where, the same thing happen.
I'm aware there are a few workarounds  (like creating a variable to keep which browser function will be called next, setting it just before every browser call ,  using named arguments on do.call, messing with the skipCalls argument of browser , etc. ) but what I really want is a way of simply printing the line number at which browser is , pretty much as it does when one press "n" m without the function arguments.  Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: `browser` takes the argument `condition`. Can you use this to let you know which `browser` is being called?

Comment: yes, sure. As I said, there are a few workarounds, but I do not want to i) have to change every browser call on my function ii)have to change every do.call call to my function