# Crash of debugging browser in R/Rstudio when called from inside do.call

Tags: r, debugging

In line with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698695/get-line-number-form-r-browser-after-do-call), the debugger browser does not show me where it has stopped when it is called from within a do.call statement. First it prints all the arguments to the console and then generally the browser is unresponsive leaving no other option than to force quit RStudio. Does anyone have experience with anything equivalent and can point to any fixes?

[This](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/154258.html)  also seems to describe a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely occurring because you have passed some dataset to a function called using `do.call`. R's default behavior when an error occurs is to enter debugging mode and print the entire function call for context. However, because `do.call` deparses each argument before calling the function, this can result in a very long statement, causing R to hang.

To limit the length of the call returned when entering `browser()` model for debugging, you can set the maximum deparse length:

```
options(deparse.max.lines = 10)
```

As of R 4.0, you can limit the length of the function call printed when entering debugging mode without changing other uses of `deparse()` by setting option `traceback.max.lines`:

```
options(traceback.max.lines = 10)
```

This should prevent the hangs caused by printing deparsed function calls when debugging within functions called by `do.call`.

A [bug has been identified with Rstudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5158) that causes it to hang even when these options are set. You may be able to debug this code within the R console or using other tools.