# Long hangs in debugging mode after hitting an error when using `Map`

Tags: r

I am experiencing very long hangs every time I enter debugging mode and hit an error (of any kind) inside a function being executed in a *specific* `Map` call. I've noticed up to 15 min of an uresponsive console.

The issue seems to be similar to what has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608323/crash-of-debugging-browser-in-r-rstudio-when-called-from-inside-do-call) and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5158), but the solutions presented have not solved it.

A few things I have noticed:

- the "hanging-after-error" only happens inside that particular `Map` call - which I can't reproduce here because it involves a lot of complex upstream code and complex objects.
- the hanging happens as soon as the function being executed by `Map` is entered (i.e., before any commands inside the function are executed)
- the hanging does not persist after exiting the function (i.e., exiting debugging mode), but exiting debugging mode also takes a very long time.

I'm using RStudio 2023.03.0 and R version 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed related to parsing a very large call (reported [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5158#issuecomment-763320513) with respect to `do.call`).
In my case, it was triggered by passing a very large `list` to `Map(..., MoreArgs)` and I imagine the same would happen with `mapply(..., MoreArgs)`.

I have solved it by replacing the `Map` with a `sapply` and passing each argument separately (even the large list), instead of grouped as a named list of arguments (as is done with `Map(..., MoreArgs)` and `do.call(..., args)`).